# Goodness-of-Fit Tests when Supports Differ

Tags: probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

I have a set of data samples and want to perform a hypothesis test. I used the Anderson-Darling-Test so far, where the test statistic is defined by
$A=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}n\frac{(\tilde{F}(x)-F(x))^2}{F(x)(1-F(x))}dF(x)$ ($\tilde{F}(x)$ is empirical distribution, ${F}(x)$ cumulative distribution, $n$ sample size).

If I now test some ($n=10$) data, say, $\{-1.06424,-0.530066,\dots,0.95493\}$. If I test this data set with a distribution that has a cut-off at $x=\pm1$, e.g. Wigner semicircle distribution for center $0$ and radius $1$, why is the p-value not zero? In fact, using standard software (Mathematica, Matlab, ...), I obtain for this data set the p-value $24.4\%$. Additionally, due to the definition of $A$, it does not matter if the forbidden value is at $x=-1.06$ or even far away at $x=-10$.

Clearly, the definition of $A$ is allowing for outlying data, but is there any way to handle such a case in a formal way? Should one take a different hypothesis test? Why (for what purpose) are forbidden values not causing the p-value to vanish?

Comment: Suggest edit to give a more readily searchable title: Something like 'Goodness-of-Fit Tests when Supports Differ'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of reasons, I think:

First, $n = 10$ is a $very$ small sample for a goodness-of-fit
test based on a comparison of the ECDF or your data and the
'null' CDF.

Second, Anderson-Darling, Kolmogorov-Smirnov and other ECDF
based GOF tests are not very good at noticing 'forbidden'
values that are barely outside the support of the null distribution.

Altogether, these tests detect 'differences' between an ECDF and a CDF by looking
at metrics like the maximum discrepancy and the 'area' of the
discrepancy. If the difference between the the ECDF of your
data and the null CDF is not large, the fact that the ECDF
has some values outside the support will hardly be noticed.

Shown below are four examples of an ECDF plot of a sample of
size $n = 20$ from $Norm(1/2, 1/6),$ each showing the CDF of
$Beta(4, 4).$ The distributions share $\mu = 1/2$ and $\sigma = 1/6.$
Agreement is generally not 'good' even if not significantly 'bad'.
However, the fact that one normal sample takes a value outside
the support $(0,1)$ of the beta distribution is not an important
consideration in the discrepancy between ECDF and CDF.

[image: graphs of cumulative distribution functions]

Comment: That's a nice example. In fact, I giving $n=10$ should just be taken as an example (have another test with $n=60$), but thanks for the remark.
Do you have a suggestion what kind of testing could be taken as an alternative? I do like quadratic ECDF tests like Anderson-Darling, but due to its construction it just does not regard data outside of the support (besides of that change of ECDF and CDF inside of support).

Comment: In practice, this issue is rare. One usually knows the support of the probability model, typically the whole real line, positive half line, $(0,1)$, and so on. Then in the 'data cleaning' phase, illegal observations are corrected (if knowable typos or computational errors) or removed before testing. In a theoretical investigation, it might make sense to pre-screen for illegal values. If I have a theoretical value of 1.2 for something that's supposed to be in $(0,1)$, then beyond doubt there is no fit. // When you have all Answ you need, please click a 'check' to accept, so we know its done.

Comment: So would you say, it is legitimate to give a statement in a publication like "obtained a p-value of 24%, but hypothesis has to be rejected because of data points outside of the support"? Up to now, I hesitated to do so since I was not sure what people normally do in such a case. I was afraid it could look like I am using a hypothesis test (where $p > \alpha$), but afterwards, however, trying to reason why this hypothesis should be rejected. Maybe it's best to only test if data is only in support?
// Sure, you'll get your check :-)

Comment: A 'pre-screen' test that detects a value outside the support of null distribution (if you know it's not a _mistake_), already supports rejection with P-value precisely 0. P-value of any subsequent test is then irrelevant. (_Mistake_ might be data entry error, incorrect reading of eqpt output, arith error in computed data, etc.) // You have not said how such 'mistakes' might occur. So it would be irresponsible of me to advise what you should say in your draft paper for pub.// Check for my Answ or someone else's--either way. If you need more, pls edit Quest, leave Comment, or start new Quest.